# Serilog not working from configuration in asp.net core 2.2 API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serilog

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
           .UseSerilog((ctx, config) => { config.ReadFrom.Configuration(ctx.Configuration); })
           .UseStartup<Startup>();
}


public class Startup
{
    public IContainer Container { get; private set; }
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Log.Warning("test");
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

}
```

appsettings.json

```
{
    "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Information",
        "System": "Information"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [

      {
        "Name": "RollingFile",
        "Args": {
          "pathFormat": "C:\\test.txt",
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffff}|{TenantName}|{RequestId}|{SourceContext}|{Level:u3}|{Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}",
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information"
        }
      }
    ]
  },

  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

I have all the packages installed

- Serilog,
- Serilog.AspCore,
- Serilog.Settings.Configuration,
- Serilog.Sink.File

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I just updated my application from ASP.NET Core 2.1 to 2.2 and now Serilog doesn't log anymore.

Comment: @Shamshiel I hit the same 2.1 to 2.2. wall.  Did you ever find the solution?

Comment: @AngryHacker For me the problem was the "<AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>" property that I added to my csproj file. It was recommended in the migration document. As far as I understand if you add this property to your project file then Serilog runs in the IIS process and may not have the rights to write logs somewhere. I just removed the property and it worked again!

Comment: @Shamshiel I did that too, but the problem is that you lose performance - which matters if you have a heavy duty site.  The solution is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54992516/how-to-get-serilog-to-log-to-the-web-output-directory-from-appsettings-json/54993335#54993335).

Comment: @AngryHacker I'm not using IIS to host my application so I'm not sure if the performance loss applies to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your config is for `RollingFile` but your package list says `Serilog.Sinks.File`. These are different. You need to add the `Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile` package and it should start working.

If you want to use the `File` sink (which, as @Kirk mentioned in the comments, is the recommended option now) then you need to change the settings to

```
"WriteTo": [
    {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
            "path": "C:\\test.txt",
            "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffff}|{TenantName}|{RequestId}|{SourceContext}|{Level:u3}|{Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}",
            "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information"
        }
    }
```

**NOTE**

The `pathFormat` should be `path` for the `File` sink

See the [Serilog File Sink Documentation](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file#json-appsettingsjson-configuration)

Comment: `Serilog.Sinks.File` is actually the recommended option now too, as it has its own improved rolling-file functionality.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and your configuration as exactly you put, and still nothing is being written.

I know logger actually works because when i do .FromFile instead of from configuration then it works, so something is off in the configuration

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer but an observation. 
I had observed a definite problem here. I have got three settingss files.

1. appsettings.json,
2. appsettings.Development.json,
3. appsettings.VivekDev.json

I have selected the profile from **launchSettings.json** such that the environment is VivekDev as follows.

```
"ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "VivekDev"
```

Now when i have the following setting in **appsettings.VivekDev.json** without having any Serilog setting in **appsettings.json**, then things are working fine.

```
  "Serilog": {
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "log.txt",
          "rollingInterval": "Day"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

But when I have

```
"Serilog": {
  "WriteTo": [ "Debug" ]
},
```

in **appsettings.json**, this is somehow overriding the setting in **appsettings.VivekDev.json**.
As per my understanding this is incorrect and the setting inside of **appsettings.VivekDev.json** should override **appsettings.json**.

And this is happening only in case of File sink. If I use other sink such as console then things are working as expected. That is the serilog setting inside of **appsettings.VivekDev.json** is correctly overriding the serilog setting of **appsettings.json**.

Something is definitely buggy here.

So of the now, I have removed the serilog settings in the **appsettings.json** and kept the serilog write to file setting in **appsettings.VivekDev.json**.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem was writing directly to c: and not using File in config which seems not to work, but writing to a different directory works.

Here is the final solution for anyone coming across this

Program.cs

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
              WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                  .UseStartup<Startup>()
                  .UseSerilog();
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
        var logConfiguration = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration);

        Log.Logger = logConfiguration.CreateLogger();
        Configuration = configuration;

}
```

appsettings.json

```
"Serilog": {
"WriteTo": [
  {
    "Name": "File",
    "Args": {
      "path": "C:\\temp\\log.txt",
      "rollingInterval": "Day"
    }
  }
]
```

}

Comment: Yes. There will be security permissions on the C: imposed by Windows. In my testing I removed the drive letter completely and forgot to change the settings I posted.