# Serilog in program class

Tags: c#, logging, asp.net-core, serilog

I am trying to log with `Serilog` in an ASP.NET Core application's `Program.cs` class. My current setup is as follows:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DoStuff();
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }
    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, builder) =>
            {
                builder.AddFile(@"C:\...\log-{Date}.txt", isJson: true);
            })
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

I can successfully log in a `Controller` class by doing:

```
public class WebhookController : Controller
{
    readonly ILogger<WebhookController> _log;
    public WebhookController(ILogger<WebhookController> log)
    {
        _log = log;
    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        _log.LogInformation("hello world");
        return View();
    }
}
```

However, when trying to replicate this in the `program` class, `_log` is not accessible in `Main(string[] args)`:

```
public class Program
{
    readonly ILogger<Program> _log;
    public Program(ILogger<Program> log)
    {
        _log = log;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DoStuff();
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, builder) =>
            {
                builder.AddFile(@"C:\...\log-{Date}.txt", isJson: true);
            })
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

How can I configure Serilog to log in the `program` class?

Comment: You added a constructor named `WebhookController` to your program class, and you expected that to what? Work?

Comment: Thanks for bringing that to my attention. No, I didn't actually do that, it's rather late where I am and I must've copy and pasted without double checking!

Comment: Got it! Thanks for clarifying. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53877037/serilog-not-working-from-configuration-in-asp-net-core-2-2-api) for some ideas on how to set up Serilog in .NET Core.

Comment: @HarryStuart Has your problem been solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the web host is built, the `IWebHost` exposes [`IWebHost.Services` Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.iwebhost.services?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Hosting_IWebHost_Services)

```
public IServiceProvider Services { get; }
```

which can be used to resolve the desired dependencies.

```
public class Program {

    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        var webHost = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();
        var services = webHost.Services;

        var log = services.GetService<ILogger<Program>>();

        DoStuff(log);

        webHost.Run();
    }

    static void DoStuff(ILogger<Program> log) {
        //...
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, builder) =>
            {
                builder.AddFile(@"C:\...\log-{Date}.txt", isJson: true);
            })
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

Remember to include `using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;` in order to have access to the `.GetService<T>()` extension method on `IServiceProvider`.

Answer (score 0):

try adding `Program` to your services.
something like this:

```
.Configure(services => services.AddTransiant<Program>())
```